# CSS Reset with attractive default styles?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I'm looking for an open source css that performs a reset and adds a reasonable default level of attractiveness.  For example, it might use better colors for the table, or give you some nice background images for a table.  It might also give you some simple css classes to make lists attractive like listmatic..

Is there something like this?

Comment: This is nearly a very good question, however a reset css seems pointless if you are going to use another stylesheet to add styles to elements.

Comment: @danixd: I thought that was exactly the point of a reset stylesheet: a known base to build on, instead of wobbly assumptions about browser defaults.

Comment: @Piskvor which is why I am saying using a CSS file to add styles after resetting them makes using the reset pointless.

Comment: @danixd lots of developers have been brainwashed into thinking you MUST use a reset stylesheet or you will have lots of headaches, which is of course untrue.

Comment: @danixd: Not really: before a reset, the base stylesheet is browser-supplied, therefore largely unknown to you, which makes for some annoying quirks. With a reset, you supply your own, well defined and known base to build upon. Similarly, when building a house, you can build on the ground, or pour a base - a level cement slab, even if your houses are dissimilar above that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this http://sencss.kilianvalkhof.com/documentation/index.html as a base

and For attractive table style you can see here http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/

Answer (score 4):

For nicely styled responsive base CSS I like [skelton](http://getskeleton.com/) and [foundation by zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/ui.php).

It's a good starting point if you're looking to get something together quickly and have it look nice. Twitter bootstrap is worth looking into as well.

Answer (score 2):

"Attractive" is a rather subjective criterion, isn't it?

I'd say start with one of the common reset CSS options (e.g. [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)), and build it into something you like.

Answer (score 1):

For a "reset" you can use [Eric Meyer's Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

**CSSesta** is public domain, doens't interfear with the styling aspect of CSS, and is more upto date than any of the common ones (Meyer, YUI, Boilerplate).

It's an actual reset sheet it has no styling just sets typical elements as we expect them to be.

There is also good outdated IE support like YUI.

It has options so if you feel you can adjust what's necessary.

http://cssesta.tk